# Send checkbox status with Ajax / JSON and save it

Tags: ajax, mysql, json

the task is actually quite simple I believe.
I want to query the status of a checkbox, pass it with $.post and JSON to a function, and then save the value.

**my-html (relevant part)**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $category->column_handle; ?>" name="<?php echo $category->column_handle; ?>" class="checkbox" <?php if($my_notifications->{$category->column_handle}){echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> value="1">
```

**my-script**

```
$('.checkbox').change(function(e){
    var parent = $(this).parents('.container');
    $.post({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
        data:{
            'action': 'myaction',
            'column': $(this).attr('id'),
            'check': $(this).prop('checked')
            }
    }).done(function(data){
        parent.find('.title').text(data.input);
    });
});
```

**my-function**

```
function my_function(){
    global $wpdb;

    $column = esc_attr($_POST['column']);
    $bool = esc_attr($_POST['check']);
    /*$id is correct and sourced elsewhere (I deleted that part)*/
    $wpdb->update('my_dataset',array($column => $bool),array('ID' => $id));

    echo json_encode(array('input' => $bool));

    die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_myaction','my_function');
```

the .done part is for testing and returns the status of the checkbox correctly. But it is not saved.
I have already tried a lot, such as treating the status as a string or passing 0 and 1. Everything without success.
Maybe one of you can help me.

Comment: Try using this: update_post_meta( $post_id = post_id, $key = 'key', $value = 'value' );

Comment: It doesn't look like OP is dealing with post meta.

Comment: Jacob is right. I use my own record so I can not use update_post_meta.

Comment: Then may be this: $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE 'my_dataset' SET $column=$bool WHERE ID=$id"));

Comment: Doesn't work either.

Comment: Perhaps: $wpdb->update('my_dataset', array($column => $bool), array('ID' => $id), array('%s'), array('%s'));

Comment: Unfortunately, not working. I really don't know why. Everything looks right and works. Only the update is not.

Comment: Assuming you have actions like this: add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_function', 'my_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_function', 'my_function' );

Comment: Yes, that's not the first time I'm using Ajax. As I said, everything works fine, no errors in the console. Even the value of $bool that is returned changes correctly. Only the line before, where the same $bool should be saved, it will not be saved.

Comment: Better add your html also above.

Comment: Added the input above. I also changed "column:..." in the js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I tried so many things that I seemingly skipped a variant that worked.

So for anyone coming by this way it works:

**my-script** as in the question:

```
'check': $(this).prop('checked')
```

**my-function** as follows:

```
function my_function(){
global $wpdb;

$column = esc_attr($_POST['column']);
$bool = esc_attr($_POST['check']);
if($bool == 'true'){$value = true;}else{$value = false;}
$wpdb->update('my_dataset',array($column => $value),array('ID' => $id));

echo json_encode(array('input' => $bool));

die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_myaction','my_function');
```

$bool has to be treated like a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
.prop()
```

method return boolean type. True or false. You should send checked value and save it into database. And in HTML get your value and set it to your checkbox.
An example you have `<input type="checkbox" name="test" class="checkbox" value="checked">`. You should send to php `$('.checkbox').val();` and then place checked attr to html.

```
<?php $checked = 'your var from database'; ?>
<input type="checkbox" <?php checked('checked', $checked); ?> name="test" class="checkbox" value="checked">
```

Something like this should work.

Comment: I'm already using value to get the column name, where the value should be updated.

Comment: Use update_post_meta() for saving checkbox status. Don`t use custom query to db. Or if your checkbox global, use update_option() function.